# CDI injecting concrete dependencies across jars

Tags: cdi, inject, named

I am a little curious about project setup.

I have a project which I am trying to update.

So I peppered some of my concrete classes with the @Named("") annotation.
The class actually extends an abstract class which implements an interface.
I want to inject the named class on a class that is not included in that jar.
What are the considerations that I need to keep in mind when doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague, so don't expect this answer to stun you with details.

> The class actually extends an abstract class which implements an interface.

This shouldn't be a problem - the final bean instance will have the the type of all the classes and interfaces in the hierarchy. Nothing to worry about.

> I want to inject the named class on a class that is not included in that jar.

Firstly, you can only inject beans into another beans. That means your other class (which is not in the same jar) has to become a bean. For this you enable the CDI in the other archive and annotate the class with desired scope.

Secondly, the other jar, has to have a dependency on the one with `@Named` beans so that the CDI container can see those beans.

Last but not least, make sure you use adequate scopes on beans. The scope belongs to certain context and each has a different lifecycle. So for instance `@ApplicationScoped` beans live from app start-up till shutdown, while `@RequestScoped` are only active during a HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  An you are right, it was a vague question.  I am new to CDI and It's capabilities.  When you say annotate the class with the desired scope, I have annotated it with the Named() annotation.  How does the scope work in the CDI container?  You mention AplicationScope live from (assuming) jvm startup-shutdown, and RequestedScoped lives per HTTP request.  Would I need to annotate both beans?

Comment: You should maybe take a look at [http://weld.cdi-spec.org/documentation/](documentation). As for your questions - `@Named` does not give the bean any scope, its goal is to makes it [http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_el_name] (accessible from EL). Bean with only `@Named` annotation will, by default, have `@Dependent` scope. On the next note - `@ApplicationScoped` lives from **CDI container startup** (the point when CDI boots and the magic starts happening) to its shutdown. And you don't need to annotate beans if `@Dependent` is good enough for you (guess it's not).

Comment: As for how scopes work in CDI container - each one has a different lifecycle after which it ceases to exist and beans linked to it will be destroyed. Such as after request for `@RequestScoped` beans. Once new request pops up, you will get a new bean. You should be able to guess how `@SessionScoped` works too. `@ConversationScoped` and `@Dependent` might be trickier and I (again) suggest Weld docs for that. You can also define your own scopes.